# Proving the Hockey Stick Identity with the Summation Identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The Summation Identity is: $\dbinom{n}{r}+\dbinom{n}{r+1}=\dbinom{n+1}{r+1}$. Is there a way to prove the hockey stick identity with this?

Hockey Stick Identity: $\dbinom{n}{r}+\dbinom{n+1}{r}+\dbinom{n+2}{r} + \cdots + \dbinom{f}{r}=\dbinom{f+1}{r+1}$

Comment: I asked if it can be proved with the summation identity.

Comment: At least one of the answer to the question above uses the summation identity  in a proof by induction.